# Get points for a semi circle

Tags: c#, xna, geometry

The title says it.
This link([Wikipedia Midpoint Circle Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)) shows how to get points for a full circle, now I need it to be for a semi circle(an arc?).
**It semi circle should be facing up, like in this image([Check this image](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcQZNjQIJkifuvr5Gus6xfUQ5WtKfnAItZPdVaXrYXF5buYCRRB8lw))
But the bottom of the circle should be open!**

For those who might think this is homework, it's not.
I'm working on a game in Xna and I want the 'rocket' that comes out of the rocket launcher to go through a certain path, a semicircle.

Comment: As you want exactly the "upper half" of the circke, you simple need to run the angle not from 0..2*pi (0..360 degrees) but just 0..pi (0..180 degrees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that algorithm is the right way to do what you want to do: describe a path. That algorithm is for plotting pixels along the path rather than describing it as such. Instead, trigonometry is probably what you want. Increase the angle from one point to another, step by step. A circle is 2π radians, so half a circle is π radians.

This should provide what you need to describe the arc. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trigonometry.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Midpoint Circle Algorithm for values where `y > 0` (assuming that the circle's midpoint is at `(0, 0)`). Anything below that is "open"

Comment: Note: I would agree with @Joe's answer that this algorithm is probably not exactly what you would want since it is more for line plotting